# how to get total comment in php for each post?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a table with the name of comments. From here I want to show total comment for each post. I tried but it shows total comments of all post. But I want only total comment for each post

```
function commeNT(){
        global $conn;
         $sql = "SELECT COUNT(`post_id`) as `totalComment` FROM `comments` WHERE post_id = `post_id`";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);                    
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($comm= mysqli_fetch_array($result)){                  
            echo $comm['totalComment'];
           }
        }
    }
```

I have a table with the name of comments. From here I want to show total comment for each post. I tried but it shows total comments of all post. But I want only total comment for each post.

Comment: what the sql return then ?

Comment: `WHERE post_id = \`post_id\`";` that doesn't look right. You probably mean `WHERE post_id = 1`?  or some other number

Comment: You just checking that the post_id of the row equals the post_id of the row.  Which obviously is going to be the case for _every_ row.  You should be passing a `$postId` into your function and using that with a bound parameter in your query.

Comment: @Qirel yes buddy

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `GROUP BY post_id`?  It is unclear from your question what your desired result it.  You show show some sample data and what the result from that data should be.

Comment: @PatrickQ the result is showing total comments of all post. I need to count total post for each post.

Comment: @Zobair You already said that in the question.  You need to _clarify_ what that means to you by providing sample data and the desired result based on that data.  The way your query is now, it looks like you may be looking for the count of comments for _a specific post_, but just doing it incorrectly.  However, I think you may actually want the count of comments for _all_ posts, _grouped by_ post_id.  Those are two very different things.

Comment: @PatrickQ yes actually I am looking for the count of comments of a specific post. Please help me.

Comment: @Zobair Then see my previous comment: "You should be passing a $postId into your function and using that with a bound parameter in your query".  As I also already said, please show us sample data along with the related desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
//This will get you a list of all posts and total comments for each.
function all_post_comments() {
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(`post_id`) as `totalComment`, `post_id` FROM `comments` GROUP BY `post_id`";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($comm = $result->fetch_array()) {
            echo $comm['post_id'] . ' Total Comments = ' . $comm['totalComment'];
        }
    }
}

//This will get you total comments for a specific post.  You have to pass post id when calling the function.
function comment_count($postId) {
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(`post_id`) as `totalComment` FROM `comments` WHERE `post_id` = $postId";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $comm = $result->fetch_array();
        echo $postId . ' Total Comments = ' . $comm['totalComment'];
    } else {
        echo "No Post Found with that id";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer? You need to explain what you posted.

Comment: @Dharman
Actually I am looking for the count of comments of a specific post. But when I am using this code that you tried , It's showing this result , in my tables I have total 9 post, from this post I am looking for the count of comments of a specific post. that's it.
7 Total Comments = 19 Total Comments = 142 Total Comments = 145 Total Comments = 7

Comment: @Zobair - i made some tweaks so you can get comment count for a single post

Comment: I fixed your PHP syntax errors, however there are still problems with this answer. `WHERE post_id` looks incorrect. I assume you wanted to use prepare instead and do `WHERE post_id=?`.